# How to lookup value from a table and select it within the current table

Tags: sql, select, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to lookup a value (c) from a table (Table2) and link it to a value (a) that I have in Table1. When I run the following lines I get an error "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated". I don't know how to resolve it.

```
SELECT
    a,
    b,
    (SELECT c FROM Table2 AS T2 WHERE T1.a = T2.a) AS c,
FROM Table1 AS T1;
```

I tried different subquery types but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: When pinned down & clearly expressed this will be a faq. (Clearly.) Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]. Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Comma before the FROM. PS Please read the editor '?' help & advanced help including re block & inline formats for code & quotes, etc. Please avoid social & meta commentary.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about bad code 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.a, T1.b, T2.c
FROM Table1 as T1
JOIN Table2 AS T2
  ON T1.a = T2.a;
```